# Ajax Call not working - is the call right

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to send an ajax call with json array

the call function is

```
if(objHasValue) {           
        alert(JSON.stringify(objArray));
        alert("before ajax call");
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'http://www.web2222.net/Test/test.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { json: JSON.stringify(objArray) },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('did it-'+data);      
                return false;
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('failure'+data.json);
            }
        });
    }       
    return false;
```

somehow it doesn't work
Do I have any mistake there?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console? Do any of the alerts fire..? Is the URL of the php page on the same domain as the page running your code?

Comment: is this code an excerpt of a function body ?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this is the problem but try something like :

```
data: { "json": JSON.stringify(objArray) }
```